# ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script when building Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have build Qt from source and now I am trying to build Qt Creator from source and get the following error: `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script`. I found [a similar thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/35794/building-qtcreator-error-unknown-module-s-in-qt-script) that suggested building qtscript library by running `make module-qtscript` manually. I did that from the Qt source folder and the build for the script library finished without any errors. However, I still get the same error when I try to prepare Qt Creator for build:

`$ qmake -r ../qt-creator/qtcreator.pro
Reading /home/aras/Projects/qt-creator/src/src.pro [/home/aras/Projects/qt-creator-build/src]
 Reading /home/aras/Projects/qt-creator/src/shared/qbs/src/lib/corelib/corelib.pro [/home/aras/Projects/qt-creator-build/src/shared/qbs/src/lib/corelib]
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script`

Locating `libQt5Script.so` finds it in my Qt source directory but not installed anywhere else on the system:

`$ locate libQt5Script.so
/home/aras/Projects/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/lib/libQt5Script.so
/home/aras/Projects/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/lib/libQt5Script.so.5
/home/aras/Projects/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/lib/libQt5Script.so.5.7
/home/aras/Projects/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/lib/libQt5Script.so.5.7.0`

Here is my Qt version:

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.7.0 in /usr/local/Qt-5.7.0/lib
```

I am following [this guide](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Creator_from_Git). What else do I need to do to get past this error and build Qt Creator?

**Edit2**
Here is my `config.status` file:

```
:~/Projects/shared-build-qt5.7.0$ cat qtbase/config.status 
#!/bin/sh
/home/aras/Projects/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/configure -prefix /usr/local/Qt-5.7.0 -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release "$@"
```

Comment: This is supposed to work, I build entire Qt and Creator from scratch each quite often and there's no problem. Heck, I've done it just today and it works OK. Make sure you're building the latest creator (4.0.3), older Qt Creator versions may not play ball with newest Qt. Your Qt build is likely borked somehow. **Please edit the question to add the contents of `qtbase/configure.cache` from the build directory.**

Comment: Your locate database is from last night, so unless you've rebuilt it right now you should be using `find` instead.

Comment: Even in the new out of source build directory I do not see any file called `*configure.cache`. Any idea what else I could try? Like you said, this should not be so hard, especially on a brand new installation.

Comment: I'm sorry - we need **`config.status`**, the unix equivalent of `configure.cache` on windows. You're on unix. I somehow missed that.

Comment: @KubaOber I have added content of `config.status`. Also dont be sorry, I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You seem to be building Qt in its source folder. That's a bad idea since you have to recreate the source folder each time you attempt a clean rebuild.

   Delete your `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0` folder and decompress it from the `.tar.xz` file.
2. Create a separate build folder, e.g.

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/Projects/5.7.0-shared-build
   ```
3. Configure for your prefix:

   ```
   cd ~/Projects/5.7.0-shared-build
   ~/Projects/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/configure \
     -prefix /usr/local/Qt-5.7.0 \
     -opensource -confirm-license \
     -debug-and-release \
     -nomake examples
   ```
4. Build

   ```
   make -j8 && make -j8 install && echo 'SUCCESS!'
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this and let you know if it works. I did not know I had to build qt our of source directory.

Comment: @Aras You did not *have* to build it that way, but if you have any mistakes or want to ensure the build is clean, you'll be fighting an uphill battle. With an out-of-source build, it's trivial: just create a new build folder.

Comment: I did a fresh build following your instructions above, but I still get the same error when trying to build qt creator: `:~/Projects/qt-creator-build$ qmake -r ../qt-creator/qtcreator.pro
Reading /home/aras/Projects/qt-creator/src/src.pro [/home/aras/Projects/qt-creator-build/src]
 Reading /home/aras/Projects/qt-creator/src/shared/qbs/src/lib/corelib/corelib.pro [/home/aras/Projects/qt-creator-build/src/shared/qbs/src/lib/corelib]
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script
`

Comment: Shouldnt the second build command be `**sudo** make -j8 install`?

Comment: Could be a sudo, depending on the permissions.